# WPF window is not opening?

Tags: c#, wpf

i am working with wpf application ,i have changed my entry point Main() to another file ,there is no error but MainWindow.xaml is not opening .Code is :

```
class AppStart : Application
    {
        [STAThread()]
        static void Main()
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("New entry point added");

            new App();

        }

        public void App()
        {
            StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

            Run();


        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it i was using wrong constructor name ..it should be `AppStart()` but i was writing `App()`..

Comment: Always a good idea to lob in a breakpoint and confirm whether or not it is being hit...